How to create animated gif from images files?
i tried this command line
D:\Captured>ffmpeg -framerate 1/2 -start_number 1 -i "D:/New folder (76)/Image%d.png" -loop -1 D:/test.gif

but getting error
[image2 @ 00000000026324a0] Could find no file with path 'D:/New folder (76)/Image%d.png' and index in the range 1-5
D:/New folder (76)/Image%d.png: No such file or directory
here is a screenshot image of my folder with the images and i want to get only the images type png that start with the name Image


I can see you have the problem with the path. Try this one.
D:\Captured>ffmpeg -framerate 1/2 -start_number 1 -i "D:\New folder (76)\Image%d.png" -loop -1 "D:\test.gif"

